# How to verify an encrypted module admin configuration from my database?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, encryption-key

When a module configuration is saved in an encrypted mode I just see dots in the admin panel, as the image below shows.

[image: How to verify an encrypted module admin configuration from Magento 2 Database]

When I check in the database via Magerun the result is that below.

```
n98-magerun2 config:store:get narvar_accord/narvar_settings/narvar_auth
```

```
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Path                                      | Scope   | Scope-ID | Value                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| narvar_accord/narvar_settings/narvar_auth | default | 0        | UmFmYWVsIENvcnJlYSBHb21lcwo= |
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I run the same command with the **--decrypt** parameter, the value is unreadable.

```
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Path                                      | Scope   | Scope-ID | Value                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| narvar_accord/narvar_settings/narvar_auth | default | 0        | և�2��ڢ�[ |
+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

How could I see the decrypted value for that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It's encrypted in **base64** use this command below to decrypt it after getting the result via Magerun's command.

```
echo UmFmYWVsIENvcnJlYSBHb21lcyA7KQo= | base64 --decode
```